# How can I expand this <input> tag?

Tags: css

This is a simplified version of my question earlier today since I didn't get a satisfactory reply.

I have a HTML and CSS code as in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wNGHz/

How can I make the `<input>` resize automatically when its parent frame is resized?

Notes:

- I prefer to use only CSS rather than JavaScript.
- The `<input>` should have 100px distance from left and right edges of the parent.

Comment: How are you passing in width for the input control. Is it in percentage?

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063158/the-input-doesnt-behave-like-a-div-when-positionabsolute) looked fine to me. I'm not sure why someone downvoted it, or why you deleted it.

Comment: @Anil Mathew: I'm not passing the width to it.@thirtydot: actually the reason I removed it was the downvote. I thought it wasn't clear enough and that's why I'm asking it again.

Comment: How is the styling/width done for the other controls in the page?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. But the page is huge and there are various styling/widths used for each element namely position:absolute,fixed,static... width:100px,width:50%,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @thirtydot semantically I want to have a simpler HTML. I can wrap
>   `<input>` with `<div>` but it's just weird to add one more element for the
>   sole purpose of styling another one. I was wondering if anyone has a
>   better solution.

Unfortunately, there is no better way. It has to do with the fact that `input` is a [replaced element](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements), which means it behaves differently to non-replaced elements such as `div`.

One difference is that `position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0` won't work in the same way on an `input` as it does on `div` (except in WebKit).

The best workaround is to wrap the `input` in a `div`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wNGHz/6/

```
<div class="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" value="test" />
</div>

.inputContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}
```

When you have `input { width: 100%; }`, it's usually a good idea to also add `box-sizing: border-box`, to make any `padding` and `border` on the `input` be counted inside the `width: 100%`: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/wNGHz/7/

Comment: it also worth to note that I discovered that when I don't specify width, either left:0 works or right:0. If I remove left:0, the input sticks to the right and vice versa. Apparently the browser by default decides for a width. It doesn't help to display:block the input either.

Answer (score 0):

The only pure CSS way I know of is by adding a width in `%`: http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/wNGHz/1/

Comment: yeah, well, I tried that one but it's not what I'm looking for. It messes with the rest of the page. One solution was to embed the <input> in a <div> and set the width of <input> to 100% while applying position:absolute;right:100px;left;100px on the <div>

Comment: @thirtydot semantically I want to have a simpler HTML. I can wrap <input> with <div> but it's just weird to add one more element for the sole purpose of styling another one. I was wondering if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: I went with the <div> solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this better way.

```
<div class="inputContainer">
<input type="text" value="test" />
</div>


input {
width: 100%;
margin:0 100px;
}
```